# getStore() in ExtJS returning undefined

Tags: extjs, undefined, datastore, extjs6

I have read many other posts with this same question, but none seem to give me the answer I need to fix the issue.

I have defined my datastore as below:

```
Ext.define('TestApp.store.tbData', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

alias: 'store.tbData',
storeId: 'tbData',


fields: [
    'name', 'number', 'key', 'priority'
],

data: {
    items: [
        {name: 'a', number: 'b', key: 'c', priority: 'd'}
    ]
},

proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'items'
    }
}
});
```

Then I also have my main view:

```
Ext.define('TestApp.Templates.tbTemplate', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
alias: 'tbTemplate',
itemId: 'tbWindow',

viewModel: {
    type: 'test'
},

requires: [
     'TestApp.Controllers.tbController',
     'TestApp.store.tbData',
     'TestApp.Controllers.dateTimeController'
],

controller: 'tbTemplate',

autoShow: true,
height: 600,
width: 600,
constrainHeader: true,
title: 'tb',

items: [
    {
        xtype: 'gridpanel',
        store: {
            type: 'tbData'
        },

        columns: [
            {
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                text: 'Name'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                dataIndex: 'number',
                text: 'Number'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                dataIndex: 'key',
                text: 'Key'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                dataIndex: 'priority',
                text: 'Priority'
            }
        ]
    }
]
});
```

Which has a controller:

```
Ext.define('TestApp.Controllers.tbController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
singleton: true,

alias: 'controller.tbTemplate',

config:{stores: ['tbData'],},

requires: [
     'TestApp.store.tbData'
],

windowOpened: function () {
    console.log(Ext.getStore('tbData'));
}
});
```

In the controller, when i call the windowOpened function, I am trying to get the datastore, so eventually I can add some more rows of data to it dynamically. I can display the test data I have put in the row, but I can't seem to connect to the datastore the way I have tried. Any help would be appreciated as to why it is returning undefined and how to tackle it.

I have tried adding it to my Application.js folder using

```
stores: ['TestApp.store.tbData']
```

with no luck either.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this: `Ext.getStore('TestApp.store.tbData')` ?

Comment: I have tried lots of variations in it and all return undefined, so I know it's connecting just not returning a value as it's finding the locations it seems

Comment: Did you try `stores: ['tbData']` in your Application.js?

Comment: One other suggestion would be to delete (or comment) the `viewModel` config and in the grid `store: 'tbData',`

Comment: I now get an error 'Uncaught TypeErrorL Cannot read property 'isBufferedStore' of undefined... I commented out viewmodel and changed the grid store to as you said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually i am not familiar with extjs 6 but i read your code and i am not understand how to bind your window opened event to controller function. so i tried your code on fiddle and it wasn't work. So i read a little bit docs about how to bind it. This is the my modifies on your code and it seems work.

[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/111t)

Comment: 'Uncaught TypeErrorL Cannot read property 'isBufferedStore' of undefined error again, everything I seem to be trying is giving me this error

Comment: By putting it separate so it works and then slowing adding my existing code to it seems to be working so far, haven't hit my previous error, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following inside windowOpened:

```
var store = Ext.StoreManager.lookup('tbData');
console.log(store);
```

or

```
var store = this.getViewModel().getStore('tbData');
console.log(store);
```

Comment: 'Uncaught TypeErrorL Cannot read property 'isBufferedStore' of undefined error again, everything I seem to be trying is giving me this error